# Массив is not defined

Tags: javascript, массивы

Беру с сервера данные и помещаю их в массив, после массив с данными хочу использовать в качестве параметра в вызове функции, но ошибка is not defined.
Получаю данные и помещаю их в массив:

```
window.load(function (offers) {
      var dataCards = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
        dataCards.push(offers[i]);
      }
    });
```

Пытаюсь использовать массив

```
var onMapPinsBlockMousedown = function (e) {
    if (e.button !== 0) {
      return;
    }
    removeCardElement();
    var targetPin;
    if (e.target.classList.contains('map__pin') && !e.target.classList.contains('map__pin--main')) {
      targetPin = e.target;
    } else if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG' && e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('map__pin') && !e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('map__pin--main')) {
      targetPin = e.target.parentElement;
    }
    if (targetPin) {
      var index = pinsElements.indexOf(targetPin);
      if (index !== -1 && index < dataCards.length) {
        renderCard(renderOfferCard(dataCards[index]));
        var cardOnMap = document.querySelector('.map__card');
        document.addEventListener('keydown', onPinEscPress);
        cardOnMap.addEventListener('mousedown', onPinCloseCard);
      }
    }
  };
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема((Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Проблема в том, что `dataCards` - локальная переменная и не видна в других функциях.

Comment: @ДарьяБаранова Передайте массив в функцию.